# Charge user on a per month & per post basis for directory

Tags: wordpress, paypal, recurring

I'm looking for a way to charge users to post to a directory site.

I've tried using the WPMU Dev directory plugin, but it didn't have this feature.

You could either charge a one time fee per post, or you could charge a monthly rate.

Oh, and for now the gateway would be PayPal.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could do that on the PayPal platform, but with the limited info I have here I would probably recommend the [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#adaptive), specifically [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

Using Preapproval, you would have users create a preapproval profile which gives you authentication to make payments on their behalf without further approval.  This way you could take payments based on any trigger you want, be it a post, a specific date coming up, or whatever.

Comment: Uh huh. Yeah. I know some of these words.

In all seriousness, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Cheers.